How to reverse the custom Navhost transition animation in jetpack compose ( when navigate to backward )
I implemented a simple type-safe navigation system for my jetpack compose app, here's how I implemented it.

@Serializable
object HomeScreen

@Serializable
object AboutScreen


@Composable
fun NavigationAnimation(){
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = HomeScreen,
    ){
        composable<HomeScreen>(
            enterTransition = {
                zoomInTransition()
            },
            exitTransition = {
                zoomOutTransition()
            }
        ){
            HomeScreen(
                onClickGoAboutScreen = {
                    navController.navigate(AboutScreen)
                }
            )
        }

        composable<AboutScreen>(
            enterTransition = {
                zoomInTransition()
            },
            exitTransition = {
                zoomOutTransition()
            }
        ){
            AboutScreen(
                onClickGoHomeScreen = {
                    navController.navigate(HomeScreen)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}


And Here's my animation's code,
// * Optimized only for the forward view (I made it slow for better visibility)
fun zoomInTransition(): EnterTransition {
    return scaleIn(
        initialScale = 0.85f, // ? When reverse/backward navigation the value will be 1.15f
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 2000, // * Actual duration 250
            easing = FastOutSlowInEasing
        )
    )+ fadeIn(
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 2000, // * Actual duration 250
            easing = FastOutSlowInEasing
        )
    )
}

fun zoomOutTransition(): ExitTransition {
    return scaleOut(
        targetScale = 1.15f, // ? When reverse/backward navigation the value will be 0.85f
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 2000, // * Actual duration 250
            easing = FastOutSlowInEasing
        )
    ) + fadeOut(
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 2000, // * Actual duration 250
            easing = FastOutSlowInEasing
        )
    )
}


All I want is when I navigate backward or pressing back button, the animation will start from reverse. For better understanding, when I Navigate from HomeScreen to AboutScreen I want the forward navigation animation, but when I go back (Or press back button) from AboutScreen to HomeScreen I want to reverse my animations.

After a days of research, I found my answer, basically the navhost composables have another type of parameter that works when we navigate back. Let me show what its all about,
// In my post, the code is looks something like this
composable<HomeScreen>(
    enterTransition = {
        zoomInTransition()
    },
    exitTransition = {
        zoomOutTransition()
    }
){
    HomeScreen(
        onClickGoAboutScreen = {
             navController.navigate(AboutScreen)
        }
    )
}


but we can add another parameters here that can allows us to define how our back navigation transition will happen. Here's the code for that,
// The answer
composable<HomeScreen>(
    enterTransition = {
        zoomInTransition()
    },
    exitTransition = {
        zoomOutTransition()
    },
    popEnterTransition = {
        popZoomInTransition() // It works when navigate back
    },
    popExitTransition = {
        popZoomOutTransition() // It works when navigate back
    }
){
    HomeScreen(
        onClickGoAboutScreen = {
             navController.navigate(AboutScreen)
        }
    )
}


